# Which is better- [obj propName] or [obj valueForKey:@"propName"] when using an id pointer?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

I have some code that assigns an object to a generic id variable and then does various things depending on the class to which said object belongs (assume that each class has the appropriate property defined and implemented correctly):

```
id obj = #<this could be one of several things>#
id result;
if ([obj class] == [MyClass1 class])
{
    result = [obj myProp1];
}
else if ([obj class] == [MyClass2 class])
{
    result = [obj valueForKey:@"myProp2"];
}
else if ([obj class] == [MyClass3 class])
{
    result = obj.myProp3; // this doesn't compile!
}
else
{
    result = nil;
}
```

Regarding the MyClass1 and MyClass2 snippets, is using KVC considered more proper or better than just sending the message to the object directly in non-dynamic cases (name of property is constant)?  Does using the KVC technique involve more overhead, thus should it only be used when the name of the property that gets invoked is dynamic?  I would like to get a feel for when it is a good idea to use KVC.

Regarding the snippet with MyClass3- why does using the dot syntax cause a compilation error?  Isn't this essentially just sending the getter accessor a message, similar to the the MyClass1 example?

Comment: Note that `isKindOfClass:` based behavior switches like this are generally an indication of a sub-optimal architecture.  While Objective-C supports dynamism and polymorphism, it isn't generally used int his fashion.

Comment: Note also that `obj.myProp3` fails to compile because `obj` is of type `id`;  dot syntax requires that the receiver be of explicit type (specifically to not perpetuate the fragility of `id` receivers to the dot syntax).

Comment: @bbum- thanks!  That makes sense (both of your comments).  The reason for the RTTI like checking is that I have one UIPopoverController that handles several styles of view controllers.  I read that it is good to reuse them, so my handler (when the POC is dismissed) has to do some checking to know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, KVC is not considered more proper. The ideal way to do this is to cast your object to the class type once you know what it is. You're also testing the class wrong. You should be using `-isKindOfClass:` instead. Your class test right now is roughly equivalent to using `-isMemberOfClass:`.

```
id obj = getObj();
id result = nil;
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[MyClass1 class]]) {
    result = [(MyClass1 *)obj myProp1];
} else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[MyClass2 class]]) {
    result = [(MyClass2 *)obj myProp2];
} else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[MyClass3 class]]) {
    result = ((MyClass3 *)obj).myProp3;
}
```

Comment: the strange thing is this: I don't get any compilation errors or warnings when sending the message with out casting (i.e. [obj myProp1]), but if I purposely misspell the property name, I do get a warning.  What gives?

Comment: When the compiler sees `id`, *any* declared method on *any* class will fulfill the "does this method exist" contract.

Comment: is the purpose of casting to enlist the aid of the compiler for catching errors?  Is there any overhead to casting?

Comment: @dreyln: Correct. Give the compiler all the help you can, and it will help you in turn. And no, the casting has no overhead. It will produce the exact same machine code. The only time in which casting will actually change the resulting code is when there are multiple classes that declare the same method name but with arguments/return value that are different primitive types (e.g. float vs int vs struct). And in that case, picking the wrong method will result in incorrect behavior.